# Query with multi_match is getting not expected order

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to find phrase in document and I need to look in title and content. Title is more important than content, so I would expect the following result:

- get first documents that have match both in title and content
- get then documents that have match only in title
- get then documents that have match only in content

It seems as quite a basic stuff.

So I've created index and data like this:

```
PUT /test_index

PUT /test_index/article/3263
{
  "id": 3263,
  "pagetitle": "Lösungen",
  "searchable_content": "abc"
}


PUT /test_index/article/1005
{
  "id": 1005,
  "pagetitle": "Lösungen",
  "searchable_content": "test! Lösungen test?"
}

PUT /test_index/article/677
{
  "id": 677,
  "pagetitle": "Lösungen",
  "searchable_content": "test Lösungen test!"
}

PUT /test_index/article/666
{
  "id": 666,
  "pagetitle": "abc",
  "searchable_content": "test Lösungen test abc"
}
```

and I run query like this:

```
GET /test_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "Lösungen",
                        "fields": ["pagetitle^2", "searchable_content"]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "pagetitle": {},
            "searchable_content": {}
        }
    }
}
```

but result is not as I expect. I get the document that have match only in title before documents that have match in both title and content like this:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": 0.5753642,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test_index",
        "_type": "article",
        "_id": "3263",
        "_score": 0.5753642,
        "_source": {
          "id": 3263,
          "pagetitle": "Lösungen",
          "searchable_content": "abc"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "pagetitle": [
            "<em>Lösungen</em>"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_index",
        "_type": "article",
        "_id": "1005",
        "_score": 0.36464313,
        "_source": {
          "id": 1005,
          "pagetitle": "Lösungen",
          "searchable_content": "test! Lösungen test?"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "searchable_content": [
            "test! <em>Lösungen</em> test?"
          ],
          "pagetitle": [
            "<em>Lösungen</em>"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_index",
        "_type": "article",
        "_id": "677",
        "_score": 0.36464313,
        "_source": {
          "id": 677,
          "pagetitle": "Lösungen",
          "searchable_content": "test Lösungen test!"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "searchable_content": [
            "test <em>Lösungen</em> test!"
          ],
          "pagetitle": [
            "<em>Lösungen</em>"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_index",
        "_type": "article",
        "_id": "666",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "id": 666,
          "pagetitle": "abc",
          "searchable_content": "test Lösungen test abc"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "searchable_content": [
            "test <em>Lösungen</em> test abc"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I was trying to do is manipulating more with fields boosting. It seems that in above case worked setting boost for both fields and using `most_fields` as type like this:

```
GET /test_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "Lösungen",
                        "fields": ["pagetitle^3", "searchable_content^2"],
                        "type": "most_fields"                       
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "pagetitle": {},
            "searchable_content": {}
        }
    }
}
```

and this gave expected result for this set of data.

However if I add 2 extra records:

```
PUT /test_index/article/999
{
  "id": 999,
  "pagetitle": "abc",
  "searchable_content": "test Lösungen test abc double match Lösungen"
}


PUT /test_index/article/1006
{
  "id": 1006,
  "pagetitle": "Lösungen and Lösungen",
  "searchable_content": "test sample"
}
```

it won't work any more because the results are like this now:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 6,
    "max_score": 2.2315955,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test_index",
        "_type": "article",
        "_id": "1006",
        "_score": 2.2315955,
        "_source": {
          "id": 1006,
          "pagetitle": "Lösungen and Lösungen",
          "searchable_content": "test sample"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "pagetitle": [
            "<em>Lösungen</em> and <em>Lösungen</em>"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_index",
        "_type": "article",
        "_id": "666",
        "_score": 1.219939,
        "_source": {
          "id": 666,
          "pagetitle": "abc",
          "searchable_content": "test Lösungen test abc"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "searchable_content": [
            "test <em>Lösungen</em> test abc"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_index",
        "_type": "article",
        "_id": "1005",
        "_score": 0.86785066,
        "_source": {
          "id": 1005,
          "pagetitle": "Lösungen",
          "searchable_content": "test! Lösungen test?"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "searchable_content": [
            "test! <em>Lösungen</em> test?"
          ],
          "pagetitle": [
            "<em>Lösungen</em>"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_index",
        "_type": "article",
        "_id": "677",
        "_score": 0.86785066,
        "_source": {
          "id": 677,
          "pagetitle": "Lösungen",
          "searchable_content": "test Lösungen test!"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "searchable_content": [
            "test <em>Lösungen</em> test!"
          ],
          "pagetitle": [
            "<em>Lösungen</em>"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_index",
        "_type": "article",
        "_id": "3263",
        "_score": 0.8630463,
        "_source": {
          "id": 3263,
          "pagetitle": "Lösungen",
          "searchable_content": "abc"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "pagetitle": [
            "<em>Lösungen</em>"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_index",
        "_type": "article",
        "_id": "999",
        "_score": 0.7876096,
        "_source": {
          "id": 999,
          "pagetitle": "abc",
          "searchable_content": "test Lösungen test abc double match Lösungen"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "searchable_content": [
            "test <em>Lösungen</em> test abc double match <em>Lösungen</em>"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

so as you see text with match only in content got higher that text with match in title and content.

Could you please give me explanation what I'm doing wrong here and how could it be fixed?

Comment: A detailed explanation would take too long, but take a look to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html to get an idea of how scoring works

Comment: @davide Thanks for link. Any way to make it work as I described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try constant score like so:

```
GET test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "pagetitle": {
                  "query": "Lösungen"
                }
              }
            },
            "boost": 2
          }
        },
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "searchable_content": "Lösungen"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "pagetitle": {},
      "searchable_content": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Constant score, according to the docs: "...wraps another query and simply returns a constant score equal to the query boost for every document in the filter." [ref](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html)
@davide's link would help you understand why even a match on searchable_content could turn up a higher score for the document. Since you want to ignore the Term Frequencies and IDFs across fields, you can use constant score on each field's match.

#### EDIT:

According to the rules listed in the original question, the above query works perfectly. But based on the comments from OP, we need to rank results on the basis of frequency of occurrence of the searched term too. So apparently, term frequency and Inverse document frequency are important, but perhaps we don't care much about the field length here (if we only want to rank results on the number of occurrences). In that case, i'd advise you to set your index up like so:

```
POST test_index_v1
{
  "mappings": {
      "article": {
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "pagetitle": {
            "type": "string",
            "norms": {
              "enabled": false
            }
          },
          "searchable_content": {
            "type": "string",
            "norms": {
              "enabled": false
            }
          }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Note: `type: string` is replaced by `type: text` in version 5 and above.

The [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html) mentioned by @davide describes the functioning of disabling norms.

Secondly, as you are running the query on a small number of documents, and assuming you have more than one shard assigned for the index, you better run the query with `search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch` as the local IDFs per shard will vary a lot. (read [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-request-search-type.html))

Thirdly, adding to the last query, what we want is to just factor in some weight of the TF-IDF. The last query was ranking the documents exactly the same, be it 2 or 3 occurrences of the search term in the same field.
We can add a bool-should block to add to the score from the constant-score blocks, like so:

```
GET test_index_v1/_search?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "pagetitle": {
                  "query": "Lösungen"
                }
              }
            },
            "boost": 2
          }
        },
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "searchable_content": "Lösungen"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "pagetitle": {
                    "query": "Lösungen",
                    "boost": 2
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "searchable_content": "Lösungen"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "pagetitle": {},
      "searchable_content": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This should give the result expected by Marcin. Only you don't need to wrap the should inside a must for these requirements.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I haven't verified it yet. But it's not that I want to ignore term frequencies. If term is 2 times in title it should be more important than when term is 1 time in title only but on the other hand when term is in both and title it's more important than when term is only in title or only in content.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work as expected. For example if in title there is Lösungen word 3 times it goes after result with this word only 2 times in title or once in title and once in searchable content.

Comment: check their scores @MarcinNabiałek. They would be according to your requirements. You did want "get first documents that have match both in title and content" so the document with "Lösungen word 3 times" should have a lesser score than "once in title and once in searchable content"

Comment: And document with "Lösungen word 3 times" would have the same score as the document "with this word only 2 times in title".

Comment: @davide, yeah i just edited the OP's query. Changed it to only bool-should

Comment: @ArchitSaxena Yes, but if there are 2 articles and one have word 3 times in title and the other only 2 times, the one with 3 times should be displayed before the one with 2 times. Both of them doesn't have the word in content.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek I've edited the answer. Please check if it works for you now. I strongly encourage you to go through the link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html for better understanding and changing the query according to your needs

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek use `?explain=true` to see a detailed breakdown of the scoring for each document in the search results.

Comment: @ArchitSaxena It seems it doesn't work this way. I've 2 records only in my index now - one with title "Lösungen" and searchable_content "test" and the other with title "Lösungen Lösungen" and searchable_content "test" and the one with 1 occurrency only is getting higher (Score 2.4222183 than the one with 2 occurrences - score 2.418256)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154872/discussion-between-archit-saxena-and-marcin-nabialek).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @ArchitSaxana it seems to be working fine now. I will show the full example (together with fuzinness) in case if anyone needed something similar:

```
PUT test_index_v1
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "ngram_filter": {
                    "type": "ngram",
                    "min_gram": 2,
                    "max_gram": 20
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "ngram_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": ["lowercase", "ngram_filter"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "_all": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "standard"
            },
            "properties": {
                "pagetitle": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "include_in_all": true,
                    "term_vector": "yes",
                    "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
                    "search_analyzer": "standard",
                    "norms": false
                },
                "searchable_content": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "include_in_all": true,
                    "term_vector": "yes",
                    "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
                    "search_analyzer": "standard",
                    "norms": false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

PUT /test_index_v1/article/1006
{
  "id": 1006,
  "pagetitle": "Lösungen Lösungen",
  "searchable_content": "test"
}


PUT /test_index_v1/article/3263
{
  "id": 3263,
  "pagetitle": "Lösungen",
  "searchable_content": "test"
}


PUT /test_index_v1/article/1005
{
  "id": 1005,
  "pagetitle": "Lösungen",
  "searchable_content": "test! Lösungen test?"
}

PUT /test_index_v1/article/677
{
  "id": 677,
  "pagetitle": "Lösungen",
  "searchable_content": "test Lösungen test!"
}

PUT /test_index_v1/article/666
{
  "id": 666,
  "pagetitle": "abc",
  "searchable_content": "test Lösungen test abc"
}

PUT /test_index_v1/article/999
{
  "id": 999,
  "pagetitle": "abc",
  "searchable_content": "test Lösungen test abc double match Lösungen"
}


PUT /test_index_v1/article/18000
{
  "id": 18000,
  "pagetitle": "abc Lösungen and Lösungen",
  "searchable_content": "test Lösungen test abc double match Lösungen"
}

PUT /test_index_v1/article/18001
{
  "id": 18001,
  "pagetitle": "abc Lösungen ",
  "searchable_content": "test Lösungen test abc double match Lösungen"
}



PUT /test_index_v1/article/18001
{
  "id": 18001,
  "pagetitle": "abc Lupungen ",
  "searchable_content": "test Lupungen test abc double match Lupungen"
}


GET test_index_v1/_search?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "pagetitle": {
                  "query": "Lupungen",
                  "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                }
              }

            },
            "boost": 2
          }
        },
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "searchable_content": {
                  "query": "Lupungen",
                  "fuzziness": "AUTO" 
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "pagetitle": {
                    "query": "Lupungen",
                     "fuzziness": "AUTO"  ,                  
                    "boost": 2
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "searchable_content": {
                  "query": "Lupungen",
                   "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "pagetitle": {},
      "searchable_content": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Result for this is:

```
{
  "took": 27,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 8,
    "max_score": 30.744686,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test_index_v1",
        "_type": "article",
        "_id": "18001",
        "_score": 30.744686,
        "_source": {
          "id": 18001,
          "pagetitle": "abc Lupungen ",
          "searchable_content": "test Lupungen test abc double match Lupungen"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "searchable_content": [
            "test <em>Lupungen</em> test abc double match <em>Lupungen</em>"
          ],
          "pagetitle": [
            "abc <em>Lupungen</em> "
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_index_v1",
        "_type": "article",
        "_id": "18000",
        "_score": 4.4021354,
        "_source": {
          "id": 18000,
          "pagetitle": "abc Lösungen and Lösungen",
          "searchable_content": "test Lösungen test abc double match Lösungen"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "searchable_content": [
            "test <em>Lösungen</em> test abc double match <em>Lösungen</em>"
          ],
          "pagetitle": [
            "abc <em>Lösungen</em> and <em>Lösungen</em>"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_index_v1",
        "_type": "article",
        "_id": "1005",
        "_score": 4.019735,
        "_source": {
          "id": 1005,
          "pagetitle": "Lösungen",
          "searchable_content": "test! Lösungen test?"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "searchable_content": [
            "test! <em>Lösungen</em> test?"
          ],
          "pagetitle": [
            "<em>Lösungen</em>"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_index_v1",
        "_type": "article",
        "_id": "677",
        "_score": 4.019735,
        "_source": {
          "id": 677,
          "pagetitle": "Lösungen",
          "searchable_content": "test Lösungen test!"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "searchable_content": [
            "test <em>Lösungen</em> test!"
          ],
          "pagetitle": [
            "<em>Lösungen</em>"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_index_v1",
        "_type": "article",
        "_id": "1006",
        "_score": 3.0157328,
        "_source": {
          "id": 1006,
          "pagetitle": "Lösungen Lösungen",
          "searchable_content": "test"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "pagetitle": [
            "<em>Lösungen</em> <em>Lösungen</em>"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_index_v1",
        "_type": "article",
        "_id": "3263",
        "_score": 2.7387147,
        "_source": {
          "id": 3263,
          "pagetitle": "Lösungen",
          "searchable_content": "test"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "pagetitle": [
            "<em>Lösungen</em>"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_index_v1",
        "_type": "article",
        "_id": "999",
        "_score": 1.3864026,
        "_source": {
          "id": 999,
          "pagetitle": "abc",
          "searchable_content": "test Lösungen test abc double match Lösungen"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "searchable_content": [
            "test <em>Lösungen</em> test abc double match <em>Lösungen</em>"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_index_v1",
        "_type": "article",
        "_id": "666",
        "_score": 1.2810202,
        "_source": {
          "id": 666,
          "pagetitle": "abc",
          "searchable_content": "test Lösungen test abc"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "searchable_content": [
            "test <em>Lösungen</em> test abc"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

what is expected. First I've got exact query match, later fuzzy results with match in title and searchable_content (sorted in right way), then fuzzy results with match in title only (sorted in right way) and finally fuzzy results with match in searchable_content only (sorted in right way)

Comment: great to hear to got it working. just wanted to add a word of caution: the dfs_query_then_fetch isn't recommended to be used on production. If the data size is sufficiently large (or you have just one shard) you wouldn't need it anyway.